# how to use for loop in javascript,jquery for number of rows in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a table and i want some action to be perform on it by using for loop in JavaScript. So could someone tell me what will be the code for it. that the for loop will work for all rows of table. Actually i have to remove a class from the table and then after that i have to apply a class to a particular row. What my task is i have to highlighted un-highlighted the selected row. when i select any row its highlighted but when i select another row then its remain highlighted and the other one too. so i want to remove the selected class from all rows of table then apply the selected class for a particular row. MY CODE IS:

```
   <style type="text/css">
    .highlight
    {
        background-color: Red;
    }
    .selected
    {
        background-color: #ffdc87;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Select(obj) {
        if (obj.className != 'selected') {

            obj.className = 'selected';
            var tbl = document.getElementById("Repaddressorbbl")
            var firstRow = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
        }
        else {
            obj.className = 'prev_class';
            var tbl = document.getElementById("Repaddressorbbl")
            var firstRow = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Question is not understandable. What actually do you need? Can you give some unworkable code-snippet on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: For your updated question you don't need a for loop, you can do it with one line of jQuery. How about you show your existing code so that people writing answers can fit in with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has implicit iteration so you don't have to manually loop over your selected rows

```
// remove all "highlight" classes from all <tr> elements
$("#your-table tr").removeClass("highlight");

// highlight row 3
$("#your-table tr:eq(2)").addClass("highlight");

// highlight row that belongs to a specific <td>
$("#my-td").parents("tr").addClass("highlight")

// etc
```

After you've removed all the `highlight` classes, you should be able to re-highlight whichever `<tr>` you want pretty easily.

If you need more help, let me know :)

Comment: What's that `:eq(2)` pseudo class? Is that something like nth-child ?

Comment: @MoeSweet that's exactly right.  In this exapmle, it'd be the third `<tr>` element.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery try:

```
 var aaa= $('#yourdivid tr:gt(0)');
 $.each(aaa, function(indx, item) {
           ////your code

            }
```

Comment: jQuery has implicit iteration so you don't have to manually iterate for tasks like this.

Comment: @macek - this answer was posted before the question was updated to say why he wanted a for loop.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks a lot. yap ans is post before edit a question.

Answer (score 0):

In POJS, you can use the table's rows collection to iterate over all the rows:

```
var rows = tableElement.rows;
for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  /* do something with rows[i] */
}
```

*rows* is a live NodeList. In some browsers it is faster to convert it to an array first because the browser doesn't know whether the list has been modified or not so each time you access it, it's updated.

More recent browsers are clever enough not to do that, but regardless it's only an issue in large tables or if performance is an issue.

In your code:

```
var firstRow = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
```

can be:

```
var firstRow = tbl.rows[0];
```